# ajax call is failing when called in a function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call an API and get and display all orders and then for each order to call another endpoint which returns the details about the worker who has placed the order and display these details along with the order details.

Using Ajax, I call the first endpoint which returns all the order. I looped through all returned orders and display the details about each order. Inside the loop I call a function which take as parameter the WorkerId (getWorker(WorkerId). This function is created outside the for loop and contains another ajax call to the second API endpoint, which returns the details about the worker.

```
var app = {}; // creating a empty object to hold the data

// getAllOrders method will make the Ajax request to the API
app.getAllOrders = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      format: 'json'
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log('Ajax is working.');
      app.displayAllOrders(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('Something went wrong.');
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}; //end app.getAllOrders function

app.getAllOrders();

app.displayAllOrders = function(allOrders) {
  console.log(allOrders);

  // getWorker method will make the Ajax request to the API
  app.getWorker = function(id) {
    console.log('Ajax is working.');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/' + id,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        format: 'json'
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log('Ajax is working.');
        app.workersInfo(result);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong.');
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }; //end app.getWorker function

  // creating a method to inject our data into the DOM
  app.workersInfo = function(worker) {
    console.log(worker);

    // Creating var for each piece of data for worker id
    var comp = $('<p>').text(worker.worker.companyName);
    var nameWorker = $('<p>').text(worker.worker.name);
    var email = $('<p>').text(worker.worker.email);
    var workerId = $('<p>').text(worker.worker.id);

    var workerInfo = $('<div>').append(nameWorker, comp, email, workerId);
    $('#allOrders').append(workerInfo);

  }; //end app.workersInfo function

  for (var i = 0; i < allOrders.orders.length; i++) {
    // creating var for each piece of data for order
    var id = $('<p>').text(allOrders.orders[i].id);
    var nameOrder = $('<h3>').text(allOrders.orders[i].name);
    var desc = $('<p>').text(allOrders.orders[i].description);
    var deadline = $('<p>').text(allOrders.orders[i].deadline);
    var workerId = $('<p>').text(allOrders.orders[i].workerId);

    // appending in div all info for the order
    var orderInfo = $('<div>').addClass('orderInfo').append(nameOrder, id, desc, deadline, workerId);
    // appending in div all info for worker
    $('#allOrders').append(orderInfo);

    // call getWorker function to display worker
    var myWorkerId = allOrders.orders[i].workerId;
    app.getWorker(myWorkerId);
  };
};
```

When `getWorker(myWorkerId)` is called, the Ajax call inside it is not called. This is called only after iterating through the loop is done. I tried with another function inside `getWorker()` instead of Ajax call and this is working. Please let me know if you can spot what I am doing wrong and how this can be fixed.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. The AJAX call is sent, but the response isn't processed until your function returns.

Comment: As an aside, my first thought after reading your description was that if this works synchronously, it will probably be glacially slow, with speed decreasing exponentially as the size of your initial order list increases. Consider potentially hiding the data behind a click or in a lazy-loaded expandable drawer... or restructuring the request to return the user data you need in a single request. You don't want to end up with a ["microservice megadisaster"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfh-VCTwMw8) :)

Comment: Switch from `$.ajax()` to the native `fetch()`, and use `Promise.all()` to run them "in order" (the array of results will have the same order at least).

Comment: Another recommendation is to create an API that allows you to provide a list of worker IDs, and returns all the worker info at once, rather than doing separate API calls for each.

Comment: i created a div with id#allOrders and executed your script on console, and its populating the data. such a waste of time reading your question.

Comment: @Dileep Nandanam  : I want information about each worker to be displayed along with order details. Currently all orders are displayed and below them all worker details. By calling getWorker(workerId) inside the for loop, I intended for each order to append worker's detail too, but this is not working